# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&' from a temporary of type 'MyClass<int>::iterator*'

Tags: c++, reference, iterator

I'm getting the following error from g++ while trying to add iterator support for my linked list class.

> ```
> LinkedList.hpp: In member function ‘Type& exscape::LinkedList<Type>::iterator::operator*() [with Type = int]’:  
> tests.cpp:51:   instantiated from here  
> LinkedList.hpp:412: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from a temporary of type ‘exscape::LinkedList<int>::iterator*’
> ```

Likely relevant code snippets:

LinkedList.hpp:

```
template <typename Type>
class LinkedList {
    private:
        struct node {
            struct node *prev;
            struct node *next;
            Type data;
        };
    public:
        class iterator : public std::iterator<...> {
            node *p;

        public:
             Type &operator*();
        };
...
};

template <typename Type>
LinkedList<Type>::iterator::iterator(struct node *in_node) : p(in_node) {}

template <typename Type>
inline Type &LinkedList<Type>::iterator::operator*() {
    return this-p->data; ///// Line 412
}
```

tests.cpp:

```
...
LinkedList<int> l1;
...
LinkedList<int>::iterator it;
for (it = l1.begin(); it != l1.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << "Element: " << *it << std::endl; ///// Line 51
}
```

I've googled (and searched SO, of course), and checked my code to no avail - either I'm missing something basic (aka. doing something stupid), or I'm missing the knowledge required. Any advice?

Comment: Looks like you might have a typo on line 412

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're returning a reference on a temporary object : `this - p->data` (I emphasized the typo) computes a pointer interval, and the result of the operation is a temporary rvalue: you can't take a reference from it.

Just remove the typo:

```
this->p->data;
```

Comment: Ugh! That was it, thanks. I guess typos fall into the former category of errors... ;)

Answer (score 2):

The issue can be demonstrated by the following snippet

```
struct A {
  int a;
  A *get() { return this - a; }
};

int main() { A a = { 0 }; assert(&a == a.get()); }
```

Replace line 412 by the following

```
return this->p->data; // "this->" is optional
```

Comment: Actually, this-> is not *always* optional. When dealing with template classes that inherit from other template classes one may need it: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#whythisarrow

Comment: @Marius, yes but here it is optional. I don't dare to try to enclose all my statements with all the exceptions found in C++ that apply to them. That wouldn't help people and it steals my time :)